# C# - Fallout4's Four Dragon - Bypassing Unhandled Exceptions?

Tags: c#, windows-7, 64-bit

[Previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445938/c-sharp-fallout-4s-four-dragon-keyup-event-instead-of-tick-event), in case y'all are curious.

Background info: [Four Dragon](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5704/?) is a C# wrapper for Fallout 4, allowing the use of C# scripts to modify the game, as well as allowing use of Papyrus (Skyrim and Fallout 4's scripting language) functions in the same C# script. The potential! THE POSSIBILITIES!

I concocted a script that runs the Papyrus functions [GetPlayerGrabbedRef()](http://www.creationkit.com/GetPlayerGrabbedRef_-_Game) and [SetMotionType](http://www.creationkit.com/SetMotionType_-_ObjectReference), which are used to make an in-game object freeze in place. Thanks to Metro Smurf, the script is much easier to read.

---

---

However, there is a rather...Blatant problem. The script registers for the F6 and F7 keys, but when F6 is pressed and the GetPlayerGrabbedRef() function is called, when the player has not grabbed a reference (a moveable in-game object), the following exception is outputted, causing the game to promptly exit:

`FATAL ERROR Unhandled exception while executing FyTyTest.FreezeObject Void OnStaticTick()`

Now, I've done some reading on how to handle unhandled exceptions, allowing the program (the Fallout 4 game in this case) to continue operation without closing via the `try` and `catch` functions, but I've not had any success; the exception still occurs, causing the game to exit when "OK" is clicked.

Alas, the various .log files that are outputted show no issue; it's as if everything functioned correctly.

Here is the latest incarnation of the script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Fallout;

public class FreezeObject : ScriptObject
{
public FreezeObject() { }

bool bGotObject = false;
ObjectReference ItemReference;
ObjectReference EmptyReference;
int itemValue;


public override void OnStaticTick()
{
    base.OnStaticTick();

    bool isF6 = Fallout.Keyboard.IsKeyJustUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F6);
    bool isF7 = Fallout.Keyboard.IsKeyJustUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F7);

    if(isF6)
    {
        try
        {
            ItemReference = Game.GetPlayerGrabbedRef();
            itemValue = ItemReference.GetGoldValue();
            if(ItemReference = EmptyReference)
            {
                // nothing else to do if we have a null reference
                return;
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            ItemReference = EmptyReference;
            itemValue = -1;
            return;
        }

    if (itemValue > -1)
    {
        bGotObject = true;
    }
            // nothing else to do; the next block is for F7
    return;
    }

    if(isF7 && bGotObject && ItemReference != EmptyReference && itemValue > -1)
    {
        ItemReference.SetMotionType(2, true);
        bGotObject = false;
    }
}
}
```

So aye. How do I go about stopping an unhandled exception from crashing the game? Or is that just not possible?

---

---

Edit: As per Corey's suggestion, I put the `try...catch` functions around all the function-y code...No dice; the exception still appears, closing the game once the exception message is closed.

Here's the new script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Fallout;

public class FreezeObject : ScriptObject
{
public FreezeObject() { }
bool bGotObject = false;
ObjectReference ItemReference;
ObjectReference EmptyReference;
int itemValue;


public override void OnStaticTick()
{try
{

    base.OnStaticTick();

    bool isF6 = Fallout.Keyboard.IsKeyJustUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F6);
    bool isF7 = Fallout.Keyboard.IsKeyJustUp(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F7);

    if(isF6)
    {
        ItemReference = Game.GetPlayerGrabbedRef();
        itemValue = ItemReference.GetGoldValue();
        if(ItemReference == EmptyReference)
        {
            // nothing else to do if we have a null reference
            return;
        }

    if (itemValue > -1)
    {
        bGotObject = true;
    }
            // nothing else to do; the next block is for F7
    return;
    }

    if(isF7 && bGotObject && ItemReference != EmptyReference && itemValue > -1)
    {
        ItemReference.SetMotionType(2, true);
        bGotObject = false;
    }
    }
catch
{
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the entire content of the `OnStaticTick` method in a `try...catch` instead of just one part of it?  The exception message isn't giving much in the way of information about what actually happened.

Comment: Yeah, the error is pretty much useless, but that's all that is given. I've not tried putting the entire thing into a `try` thing. I take it that it should go after `public override void OnStaticTick()`, not before?

Comment: Put the `try` Immediately inside the first brace, the catch before the last brace.  With their own brace sets, of course.

Comment: Sorry fer the late reply. Did as you said (updated the script on the main post to show that)...Still no dice. The error still appears, causing the game to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Four Dragon hosts its own AppDomain for the purpose of loading and executing user scripts. I haven't had many opportunities to work with custom hosts, so I don't know for sure, but I believe hosts have some control over the exception handling behavior. Assuming I'm right, I'd guess at that being the cause for your weird exception handling issues.

Your best best is to address the actual cause of the exceptions. In your code, you're checking for a null reference after you've already attempted to access a method on the object. You might want to try this:

```
if(isF6)
{
    ItemReference = Game.GetPlayerGrabbedRef();
    if(ItemReference != null && ItemReference.HandleExists())
    {
        itemValue = ItemReference.GetFormID();
        if (itemValue != 0)
        {
            bGotObject = true;
        }
    }

    // nothing else to do; the next block is for F7
    return;
}
```

I changed your `GetGoldValue()` call to `GetFormID()` since you're using it to establish whether you've got a valid `ObjectReference`.

<s>If you still have issues, I'd try to storing the form ID and using `Game.GetForm(formid)` to reacquire an object reference in the F7 block. You're relying on the assumption that the object reference remains valid between calls to `OnStaticTick`, which may not necessarily be the case. (still digging through Four Dragon's implementation, so I'm still unsure)</s>

**Edit**: Disregard - object references apparently stay valid between events.